# Python: except ValueError only for strings.

Tags: python, except

Is there a way in Python 3.3 to only except ValueError for strings? If I type a string into k, I want "Could not convert string to float" to be printed, rather than "Cannot take the square root of a negative number."

```
while True:
    try:
        k = float(input("Number? "))
```

....

```
    except ValueError:
        print ("Cannot take the square root of a negative number")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("Could not convert string to float")
        break
```

Comment: Why are you having 2 except for `ValueError`?

Comment: You're not taking a square root anywhere in the code, so why is that first `except ValueError` there at all?

Comment: I am beginner to Python so I may not have done this correctly. I need two separate messages to be printed, one for negative numbers, and one for strings. I am not sure how to do this with one exception.

Comment: You could also just print the exception. For a string, you get `ValueError: count not convert string to float: 'fdsdfsd'`. For a negative number, you get `ValueError: math domain error`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to handle exceptions different depending on their origin, it is best to separate the different code parts that can throw the exceptions. Then you can just put a try/except block around the respective statement that throws the exception, e.g.:

```
while True:
    try:
        k = float(input("Number? "))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Could not convert string to float")
        break
    try:
        s = math.sqrt(k)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Cannot take the square root of a negative number")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just remove your other `except ValueError`:

```
while True:
    try:
        k = float(input("Number? "))
```

....

```
    except ValueError:
        print ("Could not convert string to float")
        break
```

If you want to check if number is negative, just.. check if it's negative:

```
if k < 0:
   print("Number is negative!")
```